# Executing MSTest using MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild, mstest, msbuild-4.0, .net-4.6.2

I am using MSbuild to build and deploy .NET 4.6.2 project. I have `Main.proj` file with the following configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <PublishProfileName>$(Configuration).pubxml</PublishProfileName>
    <IntegrationDomainOutput>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)BuildOutput\</IntegrationDomainOutput>
    <VisualStudioVersion>14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <Framework40Dir>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319</Framework40Dir>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <Target Name="Main" DependsOnTargets="Clean">
    <!--<Error Condition="$(SchedulerServiceDestinationFolder)==''" Text="'SchedulerServiceDestinationFolder' property is missing." />-->   
    <CallTarget Targets="BuildAndDeployApi;" />
  </Target>  

  <Target Name="Clean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(IntegrationDomainOutput)"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="BuildAndDeployApi">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)IntegrationDomain.sln"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);
                         DeployOnBuild=true;
                         PublishProfile=$(PublishProfileName);
                         OutDir=$(IntegrationDomainOutput);
                         VisualStudioVersion=$(VisualStudioVersion);
                         Framework40Dir=$(Framework40Dir)"
             Targets="Build"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I also have corresponding `.pubxml` file for each environment.

In Jenkins then i simply run windows command `msbuild Main.proj /p:Configuration=development` which builds and deploys the project.

Now i want to execute unit tests *after* the build but *before* deployment. When `Main.proj` builds, the unit test project file `Domain.UnitTests.dll` get copied to `$(ItegrationDomainOutput)` path.

The corresponding `mstest` commmand to execute unit tests is

`mstest /testcontainer:$(ItegrationDomainOutput)\Domain.UnitTests.dll /resultsfile:TestResults.trx`

However i am not sure how do execute this command **after** build but **before** the deployment

**UPDATE 1**
There is `AfterBuild` and `AfterCompile` predefined targets which we can override. So as per the [documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2019) i have updated my proj file. I have override `AfterCompile` target and then Updated `Build` target's `DependsOnTargets` attribute.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  

  ... This part is same as original
  ... Removed for Brevity purpose 

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="AfterCompile"/>

  <Target Name="BuildAndDeployApi">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)IntegrationDomain.sln"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);
                         DeployOnBuild=true;
                         PublishProfile=$(PublishProfileName);
                         OutDir=$(IntegrationDomainOutput);
                         VisualStudioVersion=$(VisualStudioVersion);
                         Framework40Dir=$(Framework40Dir)"
             Targets="Build"/>
  </Target>  

  <Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <!--Run MSTest.exe-->  
      <Exec Command="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe /testcontainer:$(IntegrationDomainOutput)\Domain.UnitTests.dll" >       
      </Exec> 
  </Target>

</Project>
```

However, `AfterCompile` target never get executed

Comment: Since you run build and deploy a project on Jenkins, make sense to add a build step to run tests between build and deploy, IMO

Comment: issue is in `.proj` file the `BuildAndDeployApi` target builds and deploy. I Dont know how to separate those two steps